# Retrieve Key at Index with For Loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, key

I feel as though I must be missing something very obvious, or [C# is simply lacking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/iteration-statements) a feature I've come to expect.

There are typically three `for` loops in programming.

**#1** `for (iterator; limit; increment) {}`

Increments the `iterator` after each loop, until it hits the limit.

**#2** `for (key in object) {}`

Assigns `key` the value of the **left-half** of the `key:value` pair at each entry of object.

**#3** `foreach (value in object) {}`

Assigns `value` the value of the **right-half** of the `key:value` pair at each entry of object.

I'm aware that `foreach` can use a [`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.2), but this necessitates assigning a much larger variable the reference to `key` *and* `value`.  I don't care about the value, nor do I want to datatype it.

Where is **#2** `for in` for C#?

Comment: There is no #2 in C#. Use number 3 instead. You can iterate over keys, values, or KeyValuePairs (assuming `object` is a `Dictionary`)

Comment: Do you mean you want to iterate over list of Dictionary keys?

Comment: You can do a `foreach (var key in object.keys)` (assuming object is a `Dictionary`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `foreach (var key in object.keys)` (assuming object is a `Dictionary`) :

```
  Dictionary<object, object> dict = new Dictionary<object, object>();
  foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
  {
    var value = dict[key]; //Not required
  }
```

You could also iterate through `Values` instead of `Keys`...but of course it would be impossible to retrieve the corresponding key.

Comment: Isn't that #3 above?

Comment: @RufusL No, #3 returns a `KeyValuePair` whereas this returns the type of key (`Object` in this case).

Comment: The use of `value` above is unnecessary, but included for completeness.

Comment: Well, not if `object` is `dict.Keys`... Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, though. But #2 is a `for` and #3 is a `foreach`.

Comment: There obviously is no "`for`" loop to do this.  I think this is the closest to what the author is looking for.  Of course I could be misunderstanding as well.

Comment: You hit it on the head.  Thank you, MikeH.  Though, I imagine this mostly applies to `Dictionary` that uses both a `.Values` & `.Keys` sub-objects.  Though abnormal, using the same pattern on an `ArrayList` would not be possible due to their absence.

Answer (score 0):

In adition to @MikeH,

if your intention is to iterate over pure object to get Variable Names as Key and its values as values then you can do this with reflection. here is the example

```
public class Test
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
    public string Prop3 {get; set;}
    public string Prop4 {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            var test = new Test(){
                Prop1 = "Test1",
                Prop2 = "Test2",
                Prop3 = "Test3",
                Prop4 = "Test4"
            };

            foreach (var property in test.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(test));
            }
    }
}
```

besides, If you prefer to use dictionary again you can use

```
var dict = test.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x=> x.GetValue(test));
foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", key, dict[key]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Although, Reflection would incur more overhead than is commonly desired, so I'm giving this to MikeH.

Comment: @Atriace Thanks. Please also note that MikeH's answer wont work for the Test class which I mentioned.